# "Two job offers/application processes" questions (Job A vs Job B) - there are a LOT

Tags: discussion, best-practice

Is there anything we can do regarding the huge number of questions along the lines of:

- "I've been offered Job A and am waiting for an offer on Job B, can I accept Job A's offer and renege on it later?"
- "How do I turn down a job offer to accept another?"
- "Can I accept a job while waiting for another interview?"
- "How do I ask a company to speed up their interview process so that I don't have to decline another job?"

etc. Is there anything we can do about these other than flag them as duplicates? What's the preferred method to deal with them?

Comment: This one is a pretty good duplicate for many of them? http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/2322  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That's certainly a good example to tag them as a duplicate of: although I was more wondering whether we can prevent more of them coming in

Comment: I can't flesh this out for a full answer, but I'm not sure we can. A lot of people aren't going to read anything or do any research and I think in these situations it's probably best to close them as duplicates, faster. People universally don't generally read FAQs/etc and so as a community we basically have to help people people craft questions, etc, and pull out the gems and bury the.. not gems.

Comment: In addition, people tend to think that their individual experience is unique - that there is something special about their particular situation that doesn't fit the general case, and thus deserves new attention.

Answer (score 1):

In the questions relating to how to I accept an offer when I have: already accepted another; or started last week, or want to leave a company on short notice; the OP generally has already decided what they want to do, but they want help in executing the plan. That is where it seems impossible to stop people from wanting to ask their version of the question.

They always see their condition as special: I am just out of college; I had no idea the other company would make an offer; The other company is more well known; bigger; smaller; I never expected ...

Their goal is to find the perfect sentence that will allow them to change their mind, but not close a door on the first company, and not feel guilty about it.

Sometimes when the question is closed as a duplicate the OP goes quietly into the night; other times they don't. I used to flag them as duplicates but now I get the feeling that it isn't worth it because it takes too long to find an exact duplicate.